# Bing search API using Jsonp not working, invalid label

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, bing

Struggling with Bing's json request (bing search, not map), I am getting an error back that says 'Invalid Label'

My query url is:

```
var bingurl="http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=##APIKEY##&query=Honda&sources=web";


 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: bingurl,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {

                $callBack(data);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("error" + msg);
            }
        });
```

Firebug reports 'invalid label' and then dumps the json response.

**No idea what is wrong? help appreciated.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bing API URL you posted isn't JSONP, it's plain JSON.

JSONP is interpreted as raw JavaScript, in which case a JSON object's `{"something": ...` syntax is not an object literal, but a block statement with a label whose name contains quotes (hence the invalidness).

[As I understand it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx), if you want JSONP from Bing you have to tell it that by passing in parameters `...&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=`(name of global callback function).

(I'm also not sure what `data: "{}"` will do, but I don't think anything good.)

Comment: if I change the datatype to json, i get an error in the request, with a status complete.

Comment: Yep, you can't access JSON from an external domain, for security reasons. That's why JSONP was invented.

Comment: should the JsonCallback be the name of the function or the actual .js code?

Comment: I set JsonCallback=? (a literal question mark) and then I didn't need a global callback function. I just used jQuery.ajax's success param as usual. [Found here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/bing-instant-search-with-jquery-and.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just in the spirit of keeping things up-to-date, the newer Bing REST API *does* support jsonp, you just have to make sure that the "callback" parameter is "jsonp". In jQuery just change the jsonp attribute in your $.ajax() call to "jsonp" to make this work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://some.domain.com',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp'
});`
```