# JQuery getJSON callback not executing

Tags: jquery, json, bing-api

It's been a while since I've worked front-end, and I seem to have forgotten it all. I cannot get this call to the bing API to work, or even do anything . . .

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
     $.getJSON( 'http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=**my app id**6&query=sushi&sources=web', function( data ) {
         alert ( 'BAM!' );
     } );
 } );
```

I've looked at other SO questions but haven't found anything that works. The error log shows nothing. The ready function is executing, I tested that, but the getJSON callback never executes.

Is it possible the bing api is returning a malformed json?

Comment: what page is the call coming from?  [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @James not sure what you mean . . . the document is localhost/test.php . . . does it matter?

Comment: OK I remember ... so how would I access the api feed? use PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a jsonp-response for cross-domain-requests. Take a look at this: [Bing search API using Jsonp not working, invalid label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829750/bing-search-api-using-jsonp-not-working-invalid-label)